# Node.js uWS.js Multithreading Webservers only lists one of many ports

Tags: node.js, multithreading, webserver

I am migrating my uWS node.js server to be multithreaded. However, when I try to list different ports to connect to (e.g. localhost:3000/t1 and localhost:3000/t2), only one of the connections works.

I tried this:

```
const uWS = require('uWebSockets.js');
const port = 3000;
let { Worker, isMainThread, threadId } = require('worker_threads');
const os = require('os');

if (isMainThread) {
  [0, 1].forEach(() => {
    new Worker(__filename);
  });
} else {
  const wsLocation = '/' + threadId;

  uWS.App().ws(wsLocation, {
    open: (ws, req) => {
      console.log('ws connected to worker! GG ' + threadId);
    },
  }).listen(port, (token) => {
    if (token) {
      console.log('Listening to port ' + port + ' from thread ' + threadId);
    } else {
      console.log('Failed to listen to port ' + port + ' from thread ' + threadId);
    }
  });
}
```

The console tells me that both servers /t1 and /t2 have been listed, although when i try to connect like this:

```
const url = 'ws://localhost:3000/1';
// i test the previous line with 'ws://localhost:3000/2' as well

const client = new WebSocket(url);

client.onopen = () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
}
```

... one connection works and the other fails. The node.js console tells me that the first webserver that starts wins, meaning if thread t1 gets its webserver ready first then from t1 will be valid and t2 will be invalid.

Why don't both ports list? Why can't i connect to both? I am on windows.